# Gson vs JAXB to save java object (object state)

Tags: java, jaxb, gson

I want to save Java object( object state) or send it another application using network stream. I have come up with two options
Like I have this object

```
Note note = new Note();
note.setId(123);
note.setName("Test Name");
```

**1. GSON**

```
String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(note);
Systme.out.println(json);
```

**2. JAXB**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
            .newInstance(Note.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(note, sw);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
System.out.println(xmlString);
```

Like **Gson** support these

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Id.class, new IdTypeAdapter()).enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG).setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0).create();
```

**Which one recommended?**
In terms of:

1. Versioning
2. Field Naming support
3. Exposing or ignoring field

   etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying enough, I have found that **Gson** is better than **JAXB**.

It supports many things which **JAXB** might not.

1. Field annotation is not required in **Gson**, unlike **JAXB**.
2. **Gson** supports, Serializing and Deserializing Generic Types
3. Serializing and Deserializing Collection with Objects of Arbitrary Types
4. Custom Serialization and Deserialization
5. Null Object Support
6. Versioning Support
7. Excluding Fields From Serialization and Deserialization

**GSON Wins!!!**

For details read [Gson doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)